# FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE RESTRICT Error - Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Lately I have been trying to add the following foreign key in the table, with the RESTRICT Clause in Oracle with the following command.:

```
ALTER TABLE 
Employee_SalHead 
ADD CONSTRAINT PAYROLL_SHEAD_FKEY FOREIGN KEY
(
  SalHead_ID 
)
REFERENCES SalHead
(
  SalHead_ID
)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ENABLE;
```

This gave me the following error:

> Error starting at line : 11 in command - ALTER TABLE  Employee_SalHead ADD
>   CONSTRAINT PAYROLL_SHEAD_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (   SalHead_ID )
>   REFERENCES SalHead (   SalHead_ID ) ON DELETE RESTRICT ENABLE
>   Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Also if I try the same through Oracle SQL developer, I get only the options Set Null, Cascade and No Action Only.

Comment: tried, and didn't worked out , same error!!!

Comment: u r using mysql or oracle? & which version?

Comment: oracle 11g and the tool i have mentioned above is Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.3.16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle only supports `ON DELETE SET NULL` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`. You can achieve your requirement by simply doing the below query. No need to mention `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

```
ALTER TABLE Employee_SalHead 
      ADD CONSTRAINT PAYROLL_SHEAD_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(SalHead_ID)
      REFERENCES SalHead(SalHead_ID);
```

**ON DELETE NO ACTION** is Default.
From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#CNCPT1652)

> The No Action (default) option specifies that referenced key values cannot be updated or deleted if the resulting data would violate a referential integrity constraint. For example, if a primary key value is referenced by a value in the foreign key, then the referenced primary key value cannot be deleted because of the dependent data.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the posted question since the constraint does not actually do what Adempiere_HotCake attempted to do. DELETE RESTRICT would prevent deleting  a row in SalHead if a row in Employee_SalHead referenced the row via the foreign key.In Oracle (at least 11G or older), this can only be implemented with a trigger.

Comment: I suppose `foreign key` is enough to prevent the same. [FYR SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbc7c). Try deleting any row in salhead , you will get the error

Comment: Your fiddle plays nicely :). I retract my statement! Thanks!