# Adding foreign key constraint in Oracle gives missing keyword error

Tags: oracle

```
ALTER TABLE ankita.abc 
ADD CONSTRAINT abc_thid_fk FOREIGN KEY (th_id)
REFERENCES ankita.theatre (id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword  
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

As far as I know the syntax is correct. What could be the problem with this statement? I am using Oracle 11g Express Edition.

Comment: Clearly, Oracle disagrees with you on the issue of whether the syntax is correct.  You'd need to provide documentary evidence (a URL leading to the relevant section of the manual, for example) and a detailed explanation of why what you wrote meets the requirements.  Absent that documentation and analysis, all we can say is "you are suffering from delusions" when you claim to know the syntax better than the DBMS.

Comment: Take a look at [FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE RESTRICT Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958153/foreign-key-on-delete-restrict-error-oracle?rq=1).  And take another look at the manual.

Comment: Oracle does not support `on update cascade`. Which is clearly documented in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not there in Oracle Database. You are getting the error because of that; remove that.

Simply try:

```
alter table ankita.abc
add constraint abc_thid_fk FOREIGN KEY (th_id) references ankita.theatre(id);
```

Comment: @AnkitaRane:- Updated my answer!